# AngularJs disabled directive not updated on ng-click but after refreshing it will work fine

Tags: angularjs

When i click on Book button , buttons should be disabled if status is booked but  is not updated or disabled directive not updated ,but  when i refresh the page then it works fine and button is updated

```js
$scope.bookingData = function(){
    $http.post('myUrl',$scope.myRequiredParameters).
    then(function(response){
     $scope.datas = response.data.data;//here i am getting my data successfully
    });
}
$scope.booked = function(){
 $http.post('myUrl',$scope.myRequiredParameters).
    then(function(response){
     $scope.bookingData = response.data.data;//here also  i am getting my data successfully
     $scope.bookingData();//here i am calling again bookingData function to update status in 
    });

}
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="data in datas" >
 <td >  
  
         <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
          value="Cancel" ng-click="cancelled()" ng-disabled="data.status =='BOOKED' " >
           <input type="button" class="btn btn-success"
           value="Book" ng-click="booked()" ng-disabled="data.status ='BOOKED' ">
    </td>
     <td>
           <span class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 no-padding text-left-xs" >User Name. :- <b>{{data.name}}</b>   </span>   
            <span class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 no-padding text-left-xs">Name :-<b>{{data.status}}</b> </span>   
      </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: $scope not defined means you are including $scope in controller while creating

Comment: Every thing working fine only data is not updated when I click book or cancel button ,when I refresh the page data will be updated but I don't want reload page

Comment: Just check if you are using this variable in two different scopes .i.e controllers. If yes, then add watcher on it.

Comment: Thanks @rakesh - ok I can try your suggestion but i am new with angular so can you tell me where to add watcher .

Comment: @rakesh - i have tried $watch and $scope.$apply()  but still not updated.my function is called and i am getting data but in view it is not updated when i reload the page it  will be updated

Comment: Can u pls create a plnkr for this?

Comment: @rakes -sorry for that my code is too big ,i have converted in small code ,i have only problem is $scope.datas is not updated when i call  $scope.bookingData() this api again